# Barriers and synchronization points with non-atomic variables - data race?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, language-lawyer, barrier

Consider the following program:

```
int                        i{0};
std::experimental::barrier b{2};

int main()
{
    std::thread t0{[] {
        b.arrive_and_wait();
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }};

    std::thread t1{[] {
        i = 2;
        b.arrive_and_wait();
    }};

    t0.join();
    t1.join();
}
```

**Is this program guaranteed to print out `2`, even though `i` is not an atomic variable?**

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier/arrive_and_wait):

> Calls to `arrive_and_wait` synchronizes with the start of the completion phase of the barrier. The completion of the completion phase synchronizes with the return from the call.
>
> Calls to `arrive_and_drop` and `arrive_and_wait` never introduce data races with themselves or each other.

This suggests that there is a synchronization point on each `arrive_and_wait` call. However I am not sure if the compiler is allowed to reorder the read/write operations on `i`, since it is non-atomic.

Comment: Bartop is right.. "Calls to `arrive_and_wait()` synchronize with the return from the call". Therein lies your answer..
If A synchronizes with B, statements sequenced before A (`i = 2`) inter-thead happen before statements that are sequenced after B (`cout << i`).
Whether or not those statements are atomic is not relevant; It is the exact same mechanism that a mutex uses to synchronize non-atomic data between threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand from [std::barrier reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier)(my emphasis) :

> A barrier has a completion phase, which is executed by one of the participating threads once all threads in the set of participating threads arrive at the synchronization point. The arrive_and_wait and arrive_and_drop calls synchronize with the start of the completion phase; t**he end of the completion phase synchronizes with the returns from all calls blocked by its completion**.

you can assume that all changes made before barrier in different threads are visible in other threads, even if they are not not atomic. As [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) points out (my emphasis):

> Between threads, evaluation A inter-thread happens before evaluation B if any of the following is true
>
> **1) A synchronizes-with B**
>
> 2) A is dependency-ordered before B
>
> 3) A synchronizes-with some evaluation X, and X is sequenced-before B
>
> 4) A is sequenced-before some evaluation X, and X inter-thread happens-before B
>
> 5) A inter-thread happens-before some evaluation X, and X inter-thread happens-before B